# Alpha Num in Laravel Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my controller code;

```
$fields = ['country','county','gor','locauth','parlc'];
$rules = [];
foreach ($fields as $i => $field) {
   $rules[$field] = 'alpha_num|required_without_all:' . implode(',', array_except($fields, $i));
}

$validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

The `alpha_num|` part of the code is new. Before this, it worked. Now I get the error;

```
ErrorException in Validator.php line 1281:
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

If I change the `alpha_num` to some other type of validation rule (for example `email`) then the application works as expected. So is there a problem with `alpha_num` specifically? `alpha_dash` returns the same error...

***UPDATE***

Even if I just do;

```
$rules = ([
        'country' => 'alpha_num',
        'county' => 'alpha_num',
        'gor' => 'alpha_num',
        'locauth' => 'alpha_num',
        'parlc' => 'alpha_num'
        ]);
```

I still get the exact same error as before...

Comment: Why are you doing foreach?

Comment: I am checking to see if at least one value in five different multi-selects has been "clicked" by the user... This post helped me with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795338/how-do-i-validate-if-array-is-empty

Comment: Okay great. But that's not a clean way to validate in Laravel.